# Philips PH7850W(22DC785) Radio and 6 disc cd changer connection

Tags: audio, wiring

I have Philips PH7850W(22DC785) car stereo and 6 channel CD changer, I want to connect them together, I couldn't find the connection diagram, can you help me, thanks.
I make the cables myself, I can't buy them ready-made because they are expensive.

Radio wires are 10 (10pin) but CD Changer output is 6 wires (6pin)

PHİLİPS PH7850W(22DC785/24E)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the brand/model of the cd changer?

Comment: It would also be good to identify the make and model of vehicle.  I'm guessing it's something like a 1998 BMW 318i, but more detail will help a lot.  BMW used a lot of different kinds of connectors and they are not always compatible.

Comment: Thank you, the brand of the CD Changer is BMW, the model is 82111469404
@PAULSTER2

Comment: My vehicle is a 1987 BMW 316, the existing cable line connections are not available on my car anyway, I custom-make the cables myself, I plan to run this system outside the car first, then I plan to buy an E34 and mount it on it.
@Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little research on the all knowing internet and come across a link that has a PDF of the owners manual of your unit. Helps when you ask the right question.

https://archive.org › download › manual_22DC785_SM_PHILIPS › 22DC785_SM_PHILIPS_text.

This PDF has connection info, specifications and so much more. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it, if I find which cables to match with each other, I will be able to run the system.